# adding list of matches to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames that look like this:

***Payments data frame***

```
id <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
total_amt <- c(100, 100, 200, 200, 350, 350)
payments <- data.frame(id, total_amt)

--------------------
|  id  | total_amt |
--------------------
|  a   |  100      |
|  b   |  100      |
|  c   |  200      |
|  d   |  200      |
|  e   |  350      |
|  f   |  350      |
```

***Prices data frame***

```
product <- c("p1","p2","p3","p4","p5")
price <- c(100, 100, 300, 350, 350)
prices <- data.frame(product, price)

--------------------
|product|   price   |
--------------------
|  P1   |  100      |
|  P2   |  100      |
|  P3   |  300      |
|  P4   |  350      |
|  P5   |  350      |
```

I would like to create another column named `possible_match` that has a list of products that have that same `total_amt`. The resulting data frame would look like this:

```
--------------------------------------
|  id  | total_amt | possible_match  |
--------------------------------------
|  a   |  100      |     p1,p2       |
|  b   |  100      |     p1,p2       |
|  c   |  200      |     NA          |
|  d   |  200      |     NA          |
|  e   |  350      |     p4,p5       |
|  f   |  350      |     p4,p5       |
```

I know I can create a list of products that match a specific total_amt like this:

```
prices[prices$price==350,]
```

but how do then add the result to the row in the `payments` data frame?

I have been looking for an answer for a while but don't seem to find anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two-step process in base R using `aggregate` and `match`. We first group `prices` by `price` and gather all the `products` together and then use `price` from `agg_df` to `match` with `total_amt` from `payments` and give the corresponding `product` value to `possible_match`.

```
agg_df <- aggregate(product~price, prices, toString)
payments$possible_match <- agg_df$product[match(payments$total_amt, agg_df$price)]

payments

#  id total_amt possible_match
#1  a       100         p1, p2
#2  b       100         p1, p2
#3  c       200           <NA>
#4  d       200           <NA>
#5  e       350         p4, p5
#6  f       350         p4, p5
```

where `agg_df` is

```
  price product
1   100  p1, p2
2   300      p3
3   350  p4, p5
```

---

Or doing the same thing from different perspective :

```
payments$possible_matches <- sapply(payments$total_amt, function(x) 
                             as.character(prices$product[prices$price %in% x]))

payments

#  id total_amt possible_matches
#1  a       100           p1, p2
#2  b       100           p1, p2
#3  c       200                 
#4  d       200                 
#5  e       350           p4, p5
#6  f       350           p4, p5
```

Answer (score 1):

using base functions, you can first join the 2 tables using `merge`, then paste the product by each group of id and total_amt as follows

```
dat <- merge(payments, prices, by.x="total_amt", by.y="price", all.x=TRUE)
do.call(rbind, by(dat, paste(dat$id, dat$total_amt), function(x) {
    data.frame(
        id=x$id[1], 
        total_amt=x$total_amt[1],
        possible_match=paste(x$product, collapse=","))
}))
```

## data:

```
id <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
total_amt <- c(100, 100, 200, 200, 350, 350)
payments <- data.frame(id, total_amt)

product <- c("p1","p2","p3","p4","p5")
price <- c(100, 100, 300, 350, 350)
prices <- data.frame(product, price)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `dplyr`.  Using the 'prices' dataset,  we group by 'price', `summarise` the 'product' by `paste`ing the elements and then `left_join` with the 'payments' dataset

```
library(dplyr)
prices %>% 
    group_by(price) %>%
    summarise(product = toString(product)) %>% 
    left_join(payments, ., by = c(total_amt = 'price'))
#   id total_amt product
#1  a       100  p1, p2
#2  b       100  p1, p2
#3  c       200    <NA>
#4  d       200    <NA>
#5  e       350  p4, p5
#6  f       350  p4, p5
```